# Do I need to close a Reader decorator of the java.io package?

Tags: java, io

I need to parse an object and I need to wrap the Reader I receive into a PushbackReader. Do I need to close the PushbackReader in any case or is it safe enough to leave it open since it's the underlying reader (that I didn't open) that

With

```
public static MyObject parse(Reader reader) throws IOException, ParseException {
  PushbackReader pReader = new PushbackReader(reader, PUSHBACK_SIZE);
  try {
    return parseMyObject(pReader);
  } finally {
    pReader.close();
  }
}
```

Or is it safe enough to write only the following:

```
public static MyObject parse(Reader reader) throws IOException, ParseException {
  return parseMyObject(new PushbackReader(reader, PUSHBACK_SIZE));
}
```

---

For info, here's how I call my parser:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(...);
try {
  while (...) {
    list.add(MyObjectParser.parse(reader));
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Could not read the stream", e);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  throw new ParseRuntimeException("Could not parse the stream", e);
} finally {
  // No need for null check.
  reader.close();
}
```

Comment: does parseMyObject need a PushBackReader, or does it just take a normal Reader.  If parse is just taking a normal reader, the pushback reader has no effect

Comment: _since it's the underlying reader (that I didn't open) that_ ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `close()` on the `PushbackReader` if the callee will be closing the underlying `Reader`. The `PushbaseReader` is just a wrapper with a buffer that'll be garbage collected when you're done with it. Calling `close()` on it will close the underlying `Reader`, which you'll want to keep if you expect the method to be closing it.

**Update**: Based on your code it looks like you can't call `close()` on the `PushbackReader` because it'll also close your underlying `Reader`. The next iteration should fail with an exception about the stream being closed if you do that, from what I can see. E.g. this example fails:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("foo"));
new PushbackReader(reader).close();
reader.read(); // IOException: Stream closed
```

Comment: Mmm... Can someone please confirm that the GC will effectively close my underlying Reader? I fail to see why it should ever happen, and that's definitely a behavior I don't want.

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify. You _do_ need to close the underlying `Reader` from either the callee or inside this method.

Comment: It looks like you don't need to close the `PushbackReader` then. In fact isn't it a problem to close it? That should close the underlying stream and trigger an `IOException` from the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too complicated if you remember a few key points:

- **It's okay to close a stream/Reader/Writer more than once.**  A second (or subsequent) close has no effect.
- Stream wrappers (`PushBackReader`, `BufferedReader` etc.) *do* close the underlying stream when the wrapper is closed.
- The garbage collector does *not* in general automatically close a stream unless the stream owns on OS resource (file descriptor, socket etc.)
- Typically the *creator* of a stream will (using a `try`-`finally` block) close the stream when finished with it, e.g.

```
Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
try {
    parse(reader);
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

So as a general rule `parse()` should not close the reader unless it has a good reason to do so (e.g. an `IOException` has left the stream in an indeterminate state) in case the caller wishes to use the stream for something else.

It's probably not the end of the world if `parse` closes the stream when it has finished with it, but if it does then you should definitely document the fact.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice that you always close your readers - if they happen to be wrappers to other readers then they should cascade the close operation to them.

In your code snippet, it is just a matter of deciding where the responsibility resides. Someone should close the reader, either the `parse` method or the `parseMyObject` method. I prefer the `parse` method because then the code is more readable - the same method that created/opened the reader is the one closing it.
(otherwise you get into strange situations - someone else can use the `parseMyObject` and then suddenly be surprised that it closed the reader argument)

**UPDATE:**

Now that I see the update to your question, this boils down to accepting a reader parameter in a loop, and then wrapping it multiple times. I suggest that you refactor your code so you wrap it with the PushbackReader only once. Or move the initialization code of the reader into the inner method.

Comment: Normally, I don't take the responsibility of the `Reader` given in parameters. See my updated question to see how it is typically used. My main objective is "he who opens closes it".

Comment: I think we agree on the main idea, I misunderstood you initial question